# Dynamic Expression Building Error

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have searched a lot regarding this issue what is wrong here

```
Shorter version of my code is
/// companyid  is integer type value here is 220
    var cond1 = BuildExpression(companyId);
    var acntlst=entities.Accounts.Where(cond).ToList();
```

Account is a class querying against Account collection

**BuildExpression function**

```
 private static Expression<Func<Account, bool>> BuildExpression(string companyid)

 {
    var paramexp = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Account), "p");
     var proprty = typeof(Account).GetProperty("CompanyId");
     var prpexp = Expression.Property(paramexp, proprty);

     var varexp = Expression.Variable(typeof(Int32), companyid);
     var cond1 = Expression.Equal(prpexp, varexp);

     return Expression.Lambda<Func<Account, bool>>(cond1,paramexp);
    }
```

**Error message is**

```
The parameter '220' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Expression.Variable(typeof(Int32), companyid);
```

This creates a *variable* named `"220"`.
You never declared this variable or assigned it a value.

Instead, you want `Expression.Constant`, which takes a value and returns an expression which has that value.
(you will probably need to parse the string into an `int`)

However, you don't need to build this by hand at all.

Instead, you should just write `return a => a.CompanyId == companyId`